# How does IIS Express understand the config element `binding`?

Tags: iis-express

How does IIS Express understand the config element `binding`?

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1789:localhost" />
```

There are three parts, separated by colons. How are they each understood?

---

`Listen` directives in Apache config files have only two parts https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html

For example `Listen 192.0.2.1:80` means listen on the address-port combination of `192.0.2.1` and `80`.

If you write `Listen 80` that means listen on all addresses port 80.

Answer (score 0):

*:1789 means IIS Express will monitor incoming requests at 0.0.0.0:1789 and [::]:1789 for both IP v4 and v6 requests. The host name localhost is an extra requirement, so that all requests whose host header do not match it will also be dropped.